# Why are MySQL begin-while-end while-end statements not working in Navicat?

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

I made a table for `Professor` and another temporary table names and I'm trying to insert records in the `Professor` table. (See code snippet)

```
SELECT @iIndex := 1;
SELECT @iTotalRecords := Max(Id), @iIndex = Min(Id) From Names;

Begin
While @iIndex <= @iTotalRecords 
Do
  SELECT @vcName := Name From Names Where Id = @iIndex;
    Insert Into Professor (Name, Age, Rank, ResearchSpeciality, PhoneNumber) 
    Values (@vcName, 
           Cast( Rand() * 26 As Integer ) + 30,
               Case Cast( Rand() * 3  As Integer) When 0 Then 'Professor' When 1 Then 'Assistant Professor' Else 'Associate Professor' End,
               NULL, 
                 Cast( Rand() * 8888889 As Integer ) + 1111111 );


Set @iIndex = @iIndex + 1;
END While
End
```

Although each statement works individually, I can't run the whole loop to insert multiple records. I have tried adding delimiters, removing begin and end keywords etc. But Navicat keeps giving an error saying:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your `MariaDB` server version for the right syntax to
> use near `Begin`.

Please help me fix this.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Well, I am using navicat 12.1.24...not sure which version of MySql it supports :s  Where can  I check that?